# Cannot see my installed apps

Tags: xbox-one

I've installed a few apps for my xbox a few days ago - and all of a sudden when I go to my installed apps under the games & apps folder, it's empty; however, When I go to the store, I can launch apps I've already installed.

Any idea how can I make my apps visible? Thanks in advance (:

Comment: Do you have external storage?